# Using an SDL_Renderer within a texture wrapper class in SDL2

Tags: textures, sdl2, c++

I have a `CTexture` class which needs a renderer to create and show textures. I don't know the scope I should put the renderer in. I´ve got it to work as a global variable, but I don't know if it´s a good way.

`CTexture` instances will be created within other classes, so it seems to be a mess to pass the renderer as an argument.

What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best practice to be to pass the renderer instance to a `CContentLoader` class or a `CTextureFactory` class. Those classes could either be singletons, like I do, or simply instances that get passed to the parts of your code that need to create textures.

There's nothing your actual `CTexture` wrapper should need the renderer for after it has been created. Rendering should be handled by a separate class, that is not a job for `CTexture`, but instead a job for a class that's job is to render things, perhaps a `CRenderer`.

Limit the access to the `SDL_Renderer`, as if you have global access to it, you might be tempted to start changing rendering flags from various places, and that gets hairy really quick, when you suddenly need to change how the rendering works and looks in your game.

Comment: Actually, I need the renderer as a parameter to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`. If I understood what you said, that be done in a different class (like`CTextureFactory`), right?'

Comment: Yes. You probably don't even want to load textures in the texture's constructor, as that way caching & reusing texture data will become almost impossible.